# Ms access duplicated records

Tags: sql, ms-access

I`m having an issue with my MS Access query and I hope you can help me. 
I want product "ABC" to have code "6029" if the parent is anything else than "GYF", "RGY" & "DRF".

The mapping looks as follows:

```
| Output_code | Account | Product  | Parent |
+-------------+---------+----------+--------+
|        6029 | income  | ABC      |        |
|        7029 | income  | ABC      | GYF    |
|        7029 | income  | ABC      | RGY    |
|        7029 | income  | ABC      | DRF    |
+-------------+---------+----------+--------+
```

End result would be:

```
+-------------+---------+----------+--------+
|        6029 | income  | ABC      | DTF    |
|        6029 | income  | ABC      | DHS    |
|        7029 | income  | ABC      | GYF    |
|        7029 | income  | ABC      | RGY    |
|        7029 | income  | ABC      | DRF    |
+-------------+---------+----------+-------
```

How it works right now:

```
+-------------+---------+----------+--------+
|        6029 | income  | ABC      | DTF    |
|        6029 | income  | ABC      | DHS    |
|        7029 | income  | ABC      | GYF    |
|        7029 | income  | ABC      | RGY    |
|        7029 | income  | ABC      | DRF    |
|        6029 | income  | ABC      | GYF    |
|        6029 | income  | ABC      | RGY    |
|        6029 | income  | ABC      | DRF    |
+-------------+---------+----------+--------+

  Select A.*, B.Output_Code, "Product" as Comment from Source as A
  inner join Mapping as B on (B.Account=A.Account and B.Product = A.Product) 
  where (B.Parent = "" or B.Parent <> A.Parent);  
  union all  
  Select A.*, B.Output_Code, "Product+Parent" as Comment from Source as A 
  inner join Mapping as B on (B.Account=A.Account  and B.Product = A.Product 
  and A.Parent = B.Parent) where B.Parent <> "";
```

First part (Product) is not working as expected and combinations like ABC+RGY appear twice with both "6029" and "7029".

I tried using select within select (for this I introduced rowid) and it worked but right now is takes 30 min for my query to process (instead of 5 min).

```
Select A.*, B.Output_Code, "Product" as Comment from Source as A inner join 
Mapping as B on (B.Account=A.Account and B.Product = A.Product)
where (B.Parent = "" or B.Parent <> A.Parent) and A.rowid not in (Select 
A.rowid from Source as A inner join Mapping as B on (B.Account=A.Account and 
B.Product = A.Product and A.Parent = B.Parent) where B.Parent <> "");
```

Could you kindly share your ideas on what is the proper way of building the first query so it doesn`t affect the performance so heavily?

I went through the list of questions but couldn`t find anything similar.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the results you want.

Comment: What do your tables look like?  You have a `Source` and `Mapping` table - I'm guessing the first table in your question isn't the actual `Mapping` table as I can't see where the Primary Key fits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make a couple of assumptions about your base tables.
Your `Mapping` table looks like this:

```
| Output_code | Product | Parent |
|-------------|---------|--------|
| 7029        | ABC     | DRF    |
| 7029        | ABC     | GYF    |
| 7029        | ABC     | RGY    |
| 8593        | DEF     | XYZ    |
```

Your `Source` table looks like this:

```
| Product | Parent |
|---------|--------|
| ABC     | DTF    |
| ABC     | DHA    |
| ABC     | GYF    |
| ABC     | RGY    |
| ABC     | DRF    |
| DEF     | XYZ    |
| DEF     | ZXL    |
```

This SQL will return all your `Source` values with the correct `Output_code` attached.  A `Null` value is returned where there is no `Output_code`:

```
    SELECT  Mapping.Output_code
            , Source.Product
            , Source.Parent
    FROM    Source LEFT JOIN Mapping ON Source.Product = Mapping.Product AND    
                                        Source.Parent = Mapping.Parent



    | Output_code | Product | Parent |
    |-------------|---------|--------|
    |             | ABC     | DTF    |
    |             | ABC     | DHA    |
    | 7029        | ABC     | GYF    |
    | 7029        | ABC     | RGY    |
    | 7029        | ABC     | DRF    |
    | 8593        | DEF     | XYZ    |
    |             | DEF     | ZXL    |
```

If the only product is *ABC* and you only want to to replace all `NULL` values with `6029` you could update the `Mapping.Output_code` line to `NZ(Mapping.Output_code, 6029)` to do this.

[Nz Function help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/nz-function-8ef85549-cc9c-438b-860a-7fd9f4c69b6c)

```
SELECT  NZ(Mapping.Output_code,6029)
        , Source.Product
        , Source.Parent
FROM    Source LEFT JOIN Mapping ON Source.Product = Mapping.Product AND    
                                    Source.Parent = Mapping.Parent  

| Expr1000 | Product | Parent |
|----------|---------|--------|
| 6029     | ABC     | DTF    |
| 6029     | ABC     | DHA    |
| 7029     | ABC     | GYF    |
| 7029     | ABC     | RGY    |
| 7029     | ABC     | DRF    |
| 8593     | DEF     | XYZ    |
| 6029     | DEF     | ZXL    |
```

But I expect you have more than one product and want product DEF to show a different value if there's no parent available.
To do this add a third table called `NoMap` that lists the code for any product that doesn't already have one:

```
| Product | Output_code |
|---------|-------------|
| ABC     | 6029        |
| DEF     | 7593        |
```

*Primary Key:* **Product**

You can then use this new table to replace any Null values found in your table:

```
    SELECT  NZ(Mapping.Output_code, NoMap.Output_code)
            , Source.Product
            , Source.Parent
    FROM    (
             Source LEFT JOIN Mapping ON Source.Product = Mapping.Product AND    
                                         Source.Parent = Mapping.Parent)
                    LEFT JOIN NoMap ON Source.Product = NoMap.Product  

| Expr1000 | Product | Parent |
|----------|---------|--------|
| 6029     | ABC     | DTF    |
| 6029     | ABC     | DHA    |
| 7029     | ABC     | GYF    |
| 7029     | ABC     | RGY    |
| 7029     | ABC     | DRF    |
| 8593     | DEF     | XYZ    |
| 7593     | DEF     | ZXL    |
```

Answer (score 1):

"Go for the simple solution, not the perfect one"

```
SELECT 
  IIF(Parent IN ('GYF','RGY','DRF'), 7029, 6029) as Output_code
FROM
  Product
```

PS; i don't really do much Access SQL- i might not have used the correct string delimiters etc - you might need to jiggle this query around a bit

Edit: If you're looking to extend the mapping, you should consider a left join instead:

```
Select s.*, IIF(m.Output_Code IS NULL, 6029, m.output_Code) 
FROM 
  source s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  mapping m
  on (m.Account=s.Account and m.Product = s.Product and m.parent = s.parent)
```

Remove the 6029 row from the mapping table (redundant)

LEFT JOIN connects rows that match, and keeps rows from the left side (source) that don't have a match in the right (map) but puts nulls in the values for the right side. By comparison, an inner join throws away rows that don't have a match. It's the "this row from source has no match in map" quality that we want to leverage

This means the 'GYF','RGY','DRF' rows WILL have a match in the map table, they will not be null, the IIF will be false for those rows, the code from mapping will be used

Other rows will NOT have a match, the m.Output_code for those rows will be NULL, the IIF will be TRUE, the value 6029 will be used

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for devoting your time. This definately will do the trick but most probably the mapping will be extended in the near future with new parent codes... Ideally, when we're in BAU, only the static mapping table should be maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
Select A.*, NZ(B1.Output_Code, B2.Output_Code) as "Output_Code" from 
(Source as A
left join Mapping as B1 on (B1.Account=A.Account and B1.Product = A.Product and B1.Parent = A.Parent ) )
left join Mapping as B2 on (B2.Account=A.Account and B2.Product = A.Product and (B2.Parent Is Null or B2.Parent ="") )
```

Comment: Guys, I couldn't implement your ideas directly because of various reasons but the ones with NZ() are just brilliant and helped me to solve my problem. I built another query which at the end adds missing output codes and the results are there in less then 5 min. Big thank you!